# Is there a polynomial time reduction from B to A in this case?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard

Suppose we have an NP-complete problem A, an NP-hard problem B, and a polynomial time reduction from A to B exists.  Do we have a polynomial time reduction from B to A as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is an NP-complete problem, $A$ is also in NP.  Since $B$ is NP-hard, there is a polynomial-time reduction from $A$ to $B$, only by definition and without any further assumption.

So your question is essentially, "Are all NP-hard problems also in NP?", or "Are all NP-hard problems also NP-complete?"  But the answer is of course No: very hard problems could be NP-hard but outside of NP.  For example, the Halting problem is NP-hard, but obviously not in NP.

Comment: Suppose A can be reduced to a P problem, does it follow that P = NP?

Comment: Of course: then we may decide A in polynomial time; first reduce the instance to an instance of the P problem and then solve the instance by the polynomial-time algorithm for that P problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your insight!